# DbContext and Generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-4.1

With DataContext I could do something like

```
public IQueryable<T> All()
{
   return db.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

(as part of a generic repository class - the rest of the CRUD actions are handled in a similar manner)

I'm looking to see if the same is possible with DbContext : i.e. can a return a Queryable of T? Entry looks a bit like it might help, but not quite... ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to return a Queryable would be something like:

```
public virtual IQueryable GetAll()
{
    return dbContext.Set<T>();
}
```

In fact, I blogged some time ago about how to create a generic repository using EF4.1
take a look:

http://davidandersonlino.net/blog/2011/04/28/generic-repository-pattern-com-entity-framework-4-1/

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

`DbSet` implements `IQueryable`

this should work:

```
public IQueryable All()
{
    return db.Set<T>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect ... but the other david wins the correct answer for the blog post...that's most of my work done!